# How to start color picker on Mac OS?

Tags: macos

I am a complete newbie at Mac. It so happened that now I'm working on it. I have an weird issue - I can't find how to start default Color Picker?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You can turn the color picker into an application by following the guide here:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060408050920158

From the guide:

> Simply fire up AppleScript
>   (Applications -> AppleScript Editor)
>   and enter this text:
>
> `choose color`
>
> Now, save it as an application (File
>   -> Save As, and set the File Format pop-up to Application), and you're
>   done

Comment: That's awesome but for some reason the color picker application that is created is not retina ready...

Comment: On the other hand, this little free app, which does the same thing, is retina ready: http://www.northernspysoftware.com/software/colorpicker

Comment: the answer was given 2 years ago. the state of retina displays was a little more immature back then

Comment: Yes, but the thing that is so weird is that if you run the `choose color` inside the AppleScript editor it gives you a retina color picker. If you save the script as an Application it no longer opens a retina version. Quite odd.

Comment: That is a weird bug, but I'm hoping by this time there is a better solution to this than when this answer was posted.

Comment: The color picker that launches from this doesn't show the hex value like Xcode's does. Why in the world are they different???

Comment: It's now 2019, MacOS 10.15 Catalina is out, and AppleScript Editor is now **Applications > Utilities > Script Editor**, and you must hold down **Opt** to get **File > Save As** to appear.  Other than that, it works :-) . To get hex values, choose the color then switch to the 2nd tab (_RGB Sliders_) which has a field displaying them.

Comment: **esc** key will close the color picker (when launched this way normal quit / close is not available)

Answer (score 42):

You can call up the color picker from any Cocoa application (TextEdit, Mail, Keynote, Pages, etc.) by hitting Shift-Command-C

The following article explains more about using Mac OS's Color Picker.

http://www.macworld.com/article/46746/2005/09/colorpickersecrets.html

Comment: This doesn't work with 'Preview'

Comment: Thanks, really useful. However it feels really hacky to have to open a cocoa application in order to use the color picker over another one

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into NSColorWell class reference.