# How to open the Color Picker in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

Updating to Catalina broke the built-in color picker app enabled via AppleScript:
[How to start color picker on Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601341/how-to-start-color-picker-on-mac-os)

It no longer picks colors and always returns black.